# Cannot control Progressbar visibility from onActivityResult in Fragment

Tags: android, onactivityresult

I have a Fragment which contains a Progressbar. I retrieve it in `onCreateView()` method where `setVisibility()` works fine.

Now, when I try to set visibility of the same progressbar (declared in fragment at class level) inside `onActivityResult()` nothing happens. Here is the code.

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
if(requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_PROFILE_VIDEO_PATH){
        if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String profileVideoPath = data.getExtras().getString(ProfileVideoRecordingActivity.VIDEO_PROFILE_PATH);
            Log.d("DEBUG", profileVideoPath);

            //Upload to server
            File profileVideo = new File(profileVideoPath);
            if(profileVideo.exists()) {

                pbarVideoUpload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                FireBaseWrapper fileUploader = new FireBaseWrapper();
                String serverFolderPath = "videoprofile";
                String contentType = "video/mp4";
                FireBaseAfterUpload afterUpload = new FireBaseAfterUpload() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(String uploadURL) {
                        Log.d("DEBUG", "Successfully uploaded video to server");
                        Log.d("DEBUG", uploadURL);
                        pbarVideoUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                        ProfileService profileService = new ProfileService(TAG) {
                            @Override
                            protected void onPreServiceCall() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            protected void onPostServiceCall() {

                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterSuccess(Object object) {
                                ReturnCode successCode = (ReturnCode) object;
                                if(successCode.getSuccess()){
                                    Log.d("DEBUG", "Profile Video URL updated in DB");
                                }else{
                                    Log.d("DEBUG", "Profile Video URL NOT updated in DB");
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void afterError() {
                                Log.d("DEBUG", "Profile Video URL NOT updated in DB");
                            }
                        };
                        profileService.updateVideoPath(uploadURL);

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onProgress(String data) {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFaliure() {
                        Log.d("DEBUG", "Error! Didn't upload");
                        pbarVideoUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    }
                };

                try {
                    fileUploader.upload(profileVideo, profileVideo.getName(), serverFolderPath, afterUpload, contentType, false);
                }catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                    Log.e("DEBUG", "FileNotFoundException", e);
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I tried calling `setVisibility()` inside an Handler and also on UI thread using `runOnUiThread()`. Both approaches didn't work.

How can I control visibility of progressbar inside `onActivityResult()` of Fragment?

I need it as I am uploading a file inside `onActivityResult()` and need to display progress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fragments onCreate() was called after onActivityResult(). Hence the views were getting reinitialized and progressbar was not displayed.

Created a static variable isVideoUploading. Set its values appropriately in onActivityResult() and used it to show/hide progressbar in onCreate().
This solved half the problem. The progressbar was now visible when uploading started.

Second half of the problem was to hide the progressbar on complete of firebase async upload method. Problem was that since upload was being done in background thread which started in onActivityResult() there was no way for onCreateView() to fire again after upload was complete. 
For this I sent a broadcast intent using LocalBroadcastManager when upload was complete and registered it in the same fragment. Once broadcast was received I hid the progressbar.

Answer (score 0):

I think you onActivityResult not triggered as it is in fragment. Please use the below code in your activity which hold the fragment.

```
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
Fragment fragment = (Fragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(fragmentTag);
if (fragment != null) {
    fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
}
}
```

Comment: Hi. The onActivityResult() method inside fragment does get called. The file is uploaded successfully and I also get the log messages. I don't understand why progressbar visibility does not work.

Comment: is there any visible time duration between your setVisibility=true and setVisibility = false?

Comment: There isn't any explicit timer or any countdown but the Firebase upload() method takes around 4-7 secs to upload video. I want to display indeterminate progressbar during this time.

Answer (score 0):

put this

```
  pbarVideoUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Inside this also like I mentioned,

```
                            @Override
                            public void afterSuccess(Object object) {
                                ReturnCode successCode = (ReturnCode) object;
                                if(successCode.getSuccess()){
                                  pbarVideoUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                    Log.d("DEBUG", "Profile Video URL updated in DB");
                                }else{
                                    Log.d("DEBUG", "Profile Video URL NOT updated in DB");
                                }
                            }
```

Comment: The afterSuccess method of ProfileService  isn't for the actual file upload, its just for reflecting whether the url was saved in db successfully which is a rather short lived task.

That's why I have put the visibility code in afterSuccess of Firebase upload event handler.

Comment: Check the `pbarVideoUpload` is null or not?

Comment: I just checked pbarVideoUpload is not null in onActivityResult() and the statement pbarVideoUpload.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE); runs successfully. Yet, the visibility is not affected :|

Comment: check `Log.d("DEBUG", uploadURL);
                        pbarVideoUpload.setVisibility(View.GONE);` this line

Comment: What do you want me to check about that line?

Comment: Is it executing or not as like you checked in previous comment

Comment: Its executing. But visibility still doesn't change.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171002/discussion-between-koustuv-ganguly-and-chandan-pednekar).