# View is null in onActivityResult

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

For some reason, my view is null in `onActivityResult`. Here is how I have implemented it:

```
public class Player extends AppCompatActivity {
    RelativeLayout selectVideo;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        selectVideo = findViewById(R.id.selectVideo);
        selectVideo.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Player.this, SelectVideo.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 852);
        });

    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == 852){
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                if (data != null) {
                    // The view is null here
                    selectVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

and in `SelectVideo` I set the result like this:

```
public void returnToPlayer(String path){
    Intent output = new Intent();
    output.putExtra("path", path);
    setResult(RESULT_OK, output);
    finish();
}
```

I was not able to reproduce this, but I get this in crashlytics

```
Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setVisibility(int)' on a null object reference
```

I know I can do the following: (But I would like to know why this is happening)

```
if (selectVideo != null){
    selectVideo.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}
```

How is it possible for the view to be null?

---

Edit 1:

I doubt that the issue is related to my `xml`, but here it is, as requested in the comment section:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    tools:context=".Player">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/selectVideo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/addimg"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:background="@drawable/ab_add_video"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                android:id="@+id/addtxt"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="SELECT A VIDEO"
                android:layout_below="@+id/addimg"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: you have not called setcontentview(R.layout.yourxml) inside oncreate of your activity if has set please share your xml file

Comment: @NehaRathore Sorry about that, I have edited my question.

Comment: please share your layout activity_player

Comment: @NehaRathore I don't see how this will help. If there was something wrong with the `xml` the crash would happen in `onCreate`.

Comment: to check the problem i'll replicate on my machine with same code as you wrote

Comment: however if you don't want solution in that way that's ok but i cannot help without xml

Comment: add this inside oncreate uper.onCreate(savedInstanceState) before setContentView()

Comment: @NehaRathore `xml` added

Comment: Do you have `onStart()` or `onResume()` in your activity?

Comment: have you checked all calls for selectVideo, most propably it is updated within activity only because the code you have posted is up and running perfectly

Comment: @gprathour Yes, I have `onResume`. But there is nothing in `onResume` related to the view. Also, `onActivityResult ` gets called before `onResume`.

Comment: hey, I just tried your same code on my machine works fine no nullPointerException

Comment: add super for activity result and try this.
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)


    }

Comment: Can't see any problem with the code. How many of those do you have in Crashlytics? What versions? Strange device names?

Comment: Does it occur only in Crashlytics? Is the device name Batmobile? Which version of Android does it crash?

Comment: @sanjeev The crash only occurred twice the last week. It's on a OnePlus 5T running Android 9.

Comment: i have same problem xioami mi a2 lite android 10

Answer (score 0):

> **There could only be one possible reason that it might not be working.
>   The views get initialized again when `onActivityResult` is being
>   called.**

However you can try to use a static variable and then try to hide or show the views(or) reinitialize in `onActivityResult` and check if that solves your problem.

I was having my doubts though after seeing this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50343080/6514945), I was affirmed that this could be it.

I think you may not have to worry about unless it's a repeated occurrence in a device model. Also, I have no clue why this happens as this is not the intended behaviour as this could be a bug or possibly device specific.